# Cast Object[] array into String[] array RxJava

Tags: java, string, sorting, rx-java

I am trying to collect some property from list of objects into array using RxJava. I've wrote the code, but now I can't cast return type properly. So, I've tried this code:

```
Observable.just(rangeList)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .map((range) -> String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s (%d)", range, range.getElementNumber()))
            .cast(String.class)
            .toList()
            .toBlocking().first()
            .toArray();
```

But it still returns Object[], and I need String[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.toArray()` parameter:

`.toArray(new String[length]);`

It is well described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list.